# Binding on click events to context menu list elements

Tags: d3.js, onclick, contextmenu

I am generating dynamic context menus that appear when the user right clicks on a shape. I have managed to create the context menu, but I am having trouble catching the click event when the user selects an entry from the menu.

The event keeps binding to the right click action to create the context menu instead of a left click on the list items within the menu itself.

I have dug around SO a bunch and been unable to unearth something that will get me the rest of the way.

What I want is for the console.log function in this example to trigger when the user clicks a list element and pass the name of the item clicked. In a perfect world it would not trigger on the initial right click, but I'll take what I can get.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style>
.context-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  z-index:1200;
}

.context-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 4px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: default;
}

.context-menu ul li {
  padding: 4px 16px;
}

.context-menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #4677f8;
  color: #fefefe;
}
</style>
<script>

var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Grape"];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200);

var circle = svgContainer
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 30)
  .attr("cy", 30)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .on('contextmenu', function(d,i) {
  // create the div element that will hold the context menu
  d3.selectAll('.context-menu').data([1])
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'context-menu');
  // close menu
  d3.select('body').on('click.context-menu', function() {
    d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
    });
  // this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
  d3.selectAll('.context-menu')
    .html('')
    .append('ul')
    .selectAll('li')
    .data(fruits).enter()
    .append('li')

    //     THIS IS WHAT I CAN NOT GET TO WORK THE WAY I WANT IT TO WORK
    .on('click' , console.log( function(d) { return d; } + " clicked!"))


    .text(function(d) { return d; });
  d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
  // show the context menu
  d3.select('.context-menu')
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
    .style('display', 'block');
  d3.event.preventDefault();
  });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a plunkr demonstrating the code (I can't figure out why I couldn't get it to run with jsfiddle): http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/paPKKlUFtQCGpOmjQztS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mo3vmja/2/)

I basically updated your click listener to this:

```
.on('click' , function(d) { console.log(d); return d; })
```

It seems to be working fine.